# SCRIPT5009: 'Backbone' is undefined in IE11

Tags: backbone.js

I have following code, and try to run in IE11.Can not figure out what is wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script>

    var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you checked if the files exists? Neither `underscore` and `backbone` are accessible via the provided links.

Replace the source files with:

```
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min.js"></script>
```